# Count apple based on common ID between two tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two Excel tables that look like this:

Table 1

```
 A          B         C 
ID    Stocked      Sale
1       shelf      sold
5     display      sold
9       shelf      sold
12      shelf      sold
13      shelf
```

Table 2

```
 P          Q 
ID    Stocked
a2      apple
88
83
1       apple
9       apple
```

I need to count the total number of apples by common ID, given that apples are:

- stocked on the shelf in Table 1
- sold in Table 1

So, the outcome has to be 2 apples.

Here is what I have tried thus far:

```
COUNTIFS(B:B, "shelf", C:C, "sold", Q:Q, "apple")
```

I can't figure out how to count by common id...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A:A,REPT($P$2:$P$6,$Q$2:$Q$6="apple"),B:B,"shelf",C:C,"sold"))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. When I change the P and Q into ``P:P, Q:Q,``, it doesn't work as it should. Why is that?

Comment: @JimO. Don't use full column references for P and Q, only use the relevant data.  The reason is because it's evaluating that section as an array (on a per cell basis).  If you need a dynamic range, easiest way is to convert the P:Q data to a table (select only the relevant data -> Insert -> Table) and reference the table columns (so instead of `$P$2:$P$6` it might be `Table1[ID]`)

Comment: Hm. Thanks for the explanation. The thing is I do need to use P:P (dynamic range?) because I am pulling a live data, and the number of rows will evolve over time. Do you have suggestions on anther function that can be used in lieu of REPT function?

Comment: @JimO. I edited my comment shortly after originally posting it and included instructions to convert your P:Q data into a table, then reference the table columns.  That way the range will be dynamic and it won't reference full columns.

Comment: I figured out a way to adopt your suggestion. Thank you for your help.