# How to recycle long formula within the same if statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an `if` statement that looks like this:

```
=If(LONG 1000-CHARACTERS FORMULA > 0, LONG 1000-CHARACTERS FORMULA, "null")
```

In English, the cell will return the 1000-character formula output if that 1000-character formula is greater than 0.

The problem is copying and pasting the long 1000-characters formula.

A simple work around would be storing that 1000-character formula in a hidden cell (i.e., B2), then writing this:

```
=If(B2 > 0, B2, "null)
```

But, I don't want to use the above method because I have many cells with different long formulas.

Instead, is there a way to recycle the 1000-characters formula within the `If` statement? A possible outcome might look like:

```
=If(LONG 1000-CHARACTERS FORMULA > 0, xyz, "null")
```

Comment: There's probably a way to shorten the 1000-characters formula, if you can share it :-)

Comment: ^^^^^ Indeed very often a long formula is a sign that a different approach should be used. Maybe you can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59973132/edit) to provide said formula and explain what it is you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: My formula uses the formula answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59951678/count-apple-based-on-common-id-between-two-tables/59951812?noredirect=1#comment106032132_59951812  I have reference tables and variable names, which I cannot change, that are long.

Comment: You can also put that long formula in another cell off the page and then refer to that cell.  It would help narrow down any problems.  Then your if is : `=IF(ZZ1>0,ZZ1,"null")`

Answer (score 2):

You need a function which has an inverse and is only valid for positive numbers. A good candidate is

```
y=1/sqrt(x)
```

or

```
y=x^0.5
```

whose inverse is

```
x=y^-2
```

So the formula becomes

```
Iferror(((long_formula^-.5)^-2,"null")
```

However from the comments linking back to the previous question it seems that the result (of countifs) can't be a negative number so you could simplify it down to 1/(1/long_formula) as in @Gary's Student's (now deleted) answer.

**Edit**

I had forgotten that there is another way of doing this - using the Text function to format the number differently if it is negative or zero:

```
=TEXT(long_formula,"general;\n\u\l\l;\n\u\l\l")
```

The result is a string, so would need to be converted to a number if (say) you wanted to compare it with another number.

Comment: Have added another method to my answer.